# Unique gmail address on aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-cognito

I heard about a scan used against Netflix costumers based on the dots don't matter policy on gmail email addresses. They exploited the fact that e.xample@gmail.com is the same thing as ex.ample@gmail.com for google, but not for netflix.

Now I am building my application based on aws cognito authentication. It does assure that email address is unique, but, like netflix used to do, they do consider the dots. I don't want to be all thinking how someone can potentially exploit that against me, so I would like cognito to consider the "dots doesn't matter" when evaluating uniqueness. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AWS Cognito, you can do a [Pre-Signup Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html) to custom validate the user's signup data before signing them up.